# Partitions of ℤ/18ℤ

Tags: ring-theory

I want to partition $ℤ/18ℤ$ into ${0}$, units, irreducibles and reducibles.
I think the units are $1, 5, 7, 11, 13$ and $17$ but not sure if this is even right.

Comment: That’s right; the number of units is $\phi(18)=6$

Comment: Do you know how to then partition it in to {0}, irreducibles and reducibles?

Comment: You need to determine which elements are reducible and which are irreducible. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I've got this definition but don't know how to use it. X is reducible if there exist a, b ∈ R \ R× such that x = ab

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705573/irreducible-elements-mod-n

Answer (score 1):

You got the units right; now, all the numbers 4,8,16 are reducible since they are powers of 2, which is not a unit, furthermore $2 = 2 \cdot 10$ where neither 2 or 10 are units, hence 2 is reducible too, while $9=3\cdot 3$ and $6=2 \cdot 3$. It remains to check the nature of 3,10,14,15. $14 = 2 \cdot 16$, now, since 3 divides 18, we have that if $3 = a \cdot b$ we can suppose $a =3$, then check by multiplying 3 with all the non-units you can check that this is not possible, therefore 3 is irreducible. In a similar way 15 is seen to be irreducible. At last, $10 = 2 \cdot 14$.